# Return to same View if Data is not Found and Display Not Found Message in the same View

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have Search View Where user enters Employee ID, Upon Clicking Button an Action Method is Executed and user is Redirected to Employee Details View.

If Employee Id not Matches I want to Retain the Same Search View and display a Label with Employee Details not Found Message in MVC,

Please help on doing the above Fucntionality in my Controller.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Details(string firstName)
    {
        var empDetails = await _context.EmpDetails
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.FirstName == firstName);

        if (empDetails == null)
        {
            // ???
        }

        return View(empDetails);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is good practice to have ViewModel classes. Make one, and use it to transfer domain objects and messages to your view. Like this:

```
class EmpDetailsViewModel
{
    public EmpDetail Emp { get;set; }
    public string Message { get;set; }
}

[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult> Details(string firstName)
{
    var vm = new EmpDetailsViewModel();

    var empDetails = await _context.EmpDetails
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.FirstName == firstName);

    if (empDetails == null)
    {
        vm.Message = "Employee not found (or whatever)"
    }
    else
    {
        vm.Emp = empDetails;
    }

    return View(vm);
}
```

Then, in your view, just do

```
if (Model.Emp == null) 
{ 
<span>@Model.Message</span> 
} 
else 
{
<div>Emp details stuff </div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I understand is you want to return a message when Employee is not found.

Try this

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult> Details(string firstName)
{
    var empDetails = await _context.EmpDetails
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.FirstName == firstName);

    if (empDetails == null)
    {
        return Content("Employee not found");
    }

    return View(empDetails);
}
```

In view extract the message from the response.

--Edit

You can do an Ajax call like below to this action method

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#btnGetDetails").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/Employee/Details",
                data: '{firstName: "' + $("#txtSearch").val() + '" }',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

`success` call back will be triggered and the message will be available in the view. (Didn't test the script)

Comment: Can you please suggest how to read the message from response and display in the View